# How to create a .csv file in Java with an attribute that is a polynomial and label?

Tags: java, csv, attributes, rapidminer, dataformat

I have 5 numeric(katz,higuchi,boxcount,hurst,dfa) and 1 polynomial-type label-role (emotion {happy, sad, angry, fear, disgust,frustrated}) . Now how can I add those emotions in the attribute emotion in .csv if the format of the .csv is just like this: hfd,katz,hurst,box,dfa,emotion?

EDIT: I need to create a .csv file in java that has a 4 numeric and 1 polynomial-label (not sure how to describe it.), like the one in the picture from a rapidminer dataset.
 [rapidminer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqnMd.jpg)

Comment: Could you be a bit more elaborate with your question

Comment: What do polynomials have to do with any of this?